# Backbone: Direct Page Access Without Hash

Tags: backbone.js, deep-linking, backbone-routing

Answering my own question to an issue I kept running into with Backbone.js...

In my Backbone applications, I want users to be able to navigate directly to a an interior "page" without having to type a hash (#) in the URL. Out of the box, [Backbone Boilerplate](https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone-boilerplate) doesn't seem to support this even though it does support [pushState](http://backbonejs.org/#History-start).

Users already could reach any location as long as they start at the homepage, obviously. Or they could skip straight to an interior page, but only if there was a hash (#) directly after the domain or immediately after an initial slash.

I found a solution to this problem that seems to be working. I'm posting it here for others with the same problem, to see if anyone knows a better way, and because I couldn't find this exact problem addressed elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying to hack Backbone Boilerplate for a while, it occurred to me that BBB just needs the hash to be there if it isn't already.

So my solution is to append a rewrite rule to my `.htaccess` file that says if the requested page isn't found, try again with a hash after the domain.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /#$1 [R,L,NE]
</IfModule>
```

So far it seems to be working fine. This had been bugging me for a while, and I figured others might be in the same boat.

If anyone knows a better way to accomplish this, or any problems my solution may cause, please feel free to respond.